# How to use driver macOS printer ApeosPort C2060 in Linux

Tags: drivers, printing

I want to use fuji ApeosPort C2060 in Linux. But I don't see driver Linux in website fuji.

I see driver macOS I think should be fine in Linux  how to...

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: @guiverc sorry. i use linux ubuntu 18.04 but fuji apeosport c2060 don't have driver for linux . I find how to other driver exemple macOS adapt use in linux

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks very much

Comment: @Rinzwind  Now in install  packages .  i dont know how to use  you have document how to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver package we have does not support that printer. Looks like a pretty new printer so support might be added/post a remark on the launchpad requesting support.

The PPD released for the MAC should be identical to what we need in Ubuntu.

- Install dmg2img `sudo apt-get install dmg2img`
- Download the image for Mac OS to your Downloads map.

Create the "img" file and mount it:

```
dmg2img ~/Downloads/{yourdownload}.dmg /tmp/image.img
sudo mount  -o loop /tmp/image.img /mnt/iso/
```

From the imgage you need the "Payload" file with the PPDs:

```
cd /mnt/iso/
cp ppd.pkg/Payload /tmp/Payload.cpio.gz
cd /tmp
gunzip Payload.cpio.gz
mkdir ppd && cd /tmp/ppd
cpio -id < ../Payload.cpio
```

and all the PPDs should be in `Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/`

Now when adding the printer use the corresponding PPD when it asks for it.

- untested so please post in comments if any of this is flawed :)

Comment: I try . I get PPD driver but i install driver file PPD for linux not working . Show error " cups server error client-error-document-format-not-supported "

Comment: you probably need to check the content of that ppd and see if there are any unsupported features in there. no idea what is valid though so you will be on your own